# Filter/group dictionary by nested value

Tags: python, dictionary

Here‘s a simplified example of some data I have:

```
{"id": "1234565", "fields": {"name": "john", "email":"john@example.com", "country": "uk"}}
```

The wholeo nested dictionary is a bigger list of address data. The goal is to create pairs of people from the list with randomized partners where partners from the same country should be preferd. So my first real issue is to find a good way to group them by that country value.

I‘m sure there‘s a smarter way to do this than iterating through the dict and writing all records out to some new list/dict?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some more data and an example case with desired output.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is close to what you need:

```
result = {key:[i for i in value] for key, value in itertools.groupby(people, lambda item: item["fields"]["country"])}
```

What this does is use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group all people in the `people` list by their specified country. The resulting dictionary has countries as keys, and the unpacked groupings (matching people) as values. Input is expected as a list of dictionaries like the one in your example:

```
people = [{"id": "1234565", "fields": {"name": "john", "email":"john@example.com", "country": "uk"}}, 
          {"id": "654321", "fields": {"name": "sam", "email":"sam@example.com", "country": "uk"}}]
```

Sample output:

```
>>> print(result)
>>> {'uk': [{'fields': {'name': 'john', 'email': 'john@example.com', 'country': 'uk'}, 'id': '1234565'}, {'fields': {'name': 'sam', 'email': 'sam@example.com', 'country': 'uk'}, 'id': '654321'}]}
```

For a cleaner result, the looping construct can be tweaked so that only the ID of each person is included in the result dict:

```
result = {key:[i["id"] for i in value] for key, value in itertools.groupby(people, lambda item: item["fields"]["country"])}
>>> print(result)
>>> {'uk': ['1234565', '654321']}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot about the sorting. Simply sort the list of people by country before putting it through `groupby`. It should now work properly:

```
sort = sorted(people, key=lambda item: item["fields"]["country"])
```

Comment: @AlexHall may this be the reason why it is 'eating' results? While I do havE 6 items in my dict before, I get only 4 back in the grouped dict.

Comment: sorting seems to indeed be the issue here. I managed to get my data sorted as it comes in (Airtable API) but having a python way to do it would be great. Everything I found about OrderedDict completely overburdens me currently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one that uses defaultdict:

```
import collections

def make_groups(nested_dicts, nested_key):
    default = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for nested_dict in nested_dicts:
        for value in nested_dict.values():
            try:
                default[value[nested_key]].append(nested_dict)
            except TypeError:
                pass
    return default
```

To test the results:

```
import random

COUNTRY = {'af', 'br', 'fr', 'mx', 'uk'}

people = [{'id': i, 'fields': {
                               'name': 'name'+str(i),
                               'email': str(i)+'@email',
                               'country': random.sample(COUNTRY, 1)[0]}} 
          for i in range(10)]

country_groups = make_groups(people, 'country')

for country, persons in country_groups.items():
    print(country, persons)
```

Random output:

```
fr [{'id': 0, 'fields': {'name': 'name0', 'email': '0@email', 'country': 'fr'}}, {'id': 1, 'fields': {'name': 'name1', 'email': '1@email', 'country': 'fr'}}, {'id': 4, 'fields': {'name': 'name4', 'email': '4@email', 'country': 'fr'}}]
br [{'id': 2, 'fields': {'name': 'name2', 'email': '2@email', 'country': 'br'}}, {'id': 8, 'fields': {'name': 'name8', 'email': '8@email', 'country': 'br'}}]
uk [{'id': 3, 'fields': {'name': 'name3', 'email': '3@email', 'country': 'uk'}}, {'id': 7, 'fields': {'name': 'name7', 'email': '7@email', 'country': 'uk'}}]
af [{'id': 5, 'fields': {'name': 'name5', 'email': '5@email', 'country': 'af'}}, {'id': 9, 'fields': {'name': 'name9', 'email': '9@email', 'country': 'af'}}]
mx [{'id': 6, 'fields': {'name': 'name6', 'email': '6@email', 'country': 'mx'}}]
```